# What would be the value of float.MaxValue + 1 and float.MinValue - 1? Why?

Tags: c#, floating-point, overflow

Currently learning overflow and want to understand it. Appreciate any help.

Comment: It'll be `float.MaxValue` and `float.MinValue`; `1` is not large enough to change `Min/MaxValue`

Comment: You might also be interested in this article explaining gaps in floating point numbers: https://www.exploringbinary.com/the-spacing-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/

Comment: If only there were some way to find out what a computer would do with a calculation… Somebody should invent a machine that would do that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, *magnitudes* of both `Min` and `Max` values are *huge*:

```
float.MaxValue = 3.4028235E+38 
float.MinValue = -3.4028235E+38
```

that's why `1` is just *ignored*

```
float.MaxValue + 1 == float.MaxValue

float.MinValue - 1 == float.MinValue
```

If you add / subtract value which is *large enough*, say `1e32f` you'll get *infinities*:

```
float.MaxValue + 1e32f == float.PositiveInfinity

float.MinValue - 1e32f == float.NegativeInfinity
```

Comment: thank you, it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by spinning up a console app.

Here's our Main() function:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Float MaxValue: ");
        Console.WriteLine(float.MaxValue);
        Console.Write("Float MaxValue + 1: ");
        Console.WriteLine(float.MaxValue + 1);

        Console.Write("Float MinValue: ");
        Console.WriteLine(float.MinValue);
        Console.Write("Float MinValue - 1: ");
        Console.WriteLine(float.MinValue - 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Testing MaxValue == MaxValue + 1");
        Console.WriteLine(float.MaxValue == float.MaxValue + 1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

And here's the output:

```
Float MaxValue: 3.402823E+38
Float MaxValue + 1: 3.402823E+38
Float MinValue: -3.402823E+38
Float MinValue - 1: -3.402823E+38
Testing MaxValue == MaxValue + 1
True
```

Dmitry's answer explains the "why" nicely.

Comment: thanks for your help